# Load data into DataGridView from sql server in vb

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

Loading data from SQL server into datagridview but **Warning    1   Variable 'dtApplicantLists' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result in runtime.** green underline at dtApplicantLists.Load(reader)

Any help, please...

```
 Private Function GetList() As DataTable

        Dim dtApplicantLists As DataTable

        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)

            Using cmmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Gender, ChosenProg, Aggregate FROM dbo.Applicants", conn)

                conn.Open()

                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmmd.ExecuteReader()

                dtApplicantLists.Load(reader)

            End Using

        End Using

        Return dtApplicantLists

    End Function
```

Comment: Where in that code do you create a `DataTable` object? You don't, hence the issue. You obviously know how to create objects because you're doing it for the connection and the command. You need to do the same for the table.

Comment: You need to call `Set dtApplicantsList = New DataTable` - currently it is null (or `Nothing` in VB). Disclaimer: I don't use VB so my syntax might be a little off.

Comment: @Charleh, the `Set` keyword is not required and, if I'm not mistaken, not even supported in VB.NET. Also, you generally wouldn't use that long-hand form. Changing `Dim dtApplicantLists As DataTable` to `Dim dtApplicantLists As New DataTable` is the obvious option.

Comment: OT, you don't need to nest `Using` blocks unless you need to interleave code between them.. You can initialise multiple variables with a single `Using` statement. Just separate them with commas.

Comment: `Dim dtApplicantLists As New DataTable` .. And .`Dispose()` the reader after loading the table or use a `Using..End Using`  to create it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yeah - it's been a while, I can't look at VB without wincing, it's not a terse language, that's for sure!

Comment: @JQSOFT, while that is best practice, closing the connection will implicitly close the reader.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Let's do the best practice boss.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Makes sense that closing the connection will close the reader but what about reader.Dispose? Will it also .Dispose the reader? I tried to check the Reference Source but it quickly was over my head. Tested with IsNothing but it did not return True.

Comment: @Mary, I'd call `Close` over `Dispose` but, as @JQSOFT suggested, I always create the reader with a `Using` statement so it is implicitly disposed. You should pretty much always create a disposable object with a `using` statement if you finish using that object in the same method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call  dtApplicantLists = New DataTable - currently it is null (or Nothing in VB).

Answer (score 0):

`Using ... End Using` Method will guarantee you won't need to worry about warnings like this one you got, as obviously demonstrated in your Code.

```
Private Function GetList() As DataTable
        Dim SqlStr As String =
            ("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Gender, ChosenProg, Aggregate FROM dbo.Applicants")
        Using dtApplicantLists As DataTable = New DataTable
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString),
                    Cmd As New SqlCommand(SqlStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                Using Reader As SqlDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dtApplicantLists.Load(Reader)
                End Using
            End Using
            Return dtApplicantLists
        End Using
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Int32

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Sql = "select * from Product"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            DataGridView1.Data Source= ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                adapter.Update(changes)
            End If
            MsgBox("Changes Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

See the link below for some other similar, but slightly different options.

http://vb.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-datagridview-sqlserver.htm